# How to view printf output in a Win32 application on Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio

How can you view printf output in a [Win32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) application (entering with a WinMain) in [Visual Studio 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010)?

Comment: Do you want to open a separate console window from the app, or do you want to display it in a control on the main app window? Or log it to a file?

Comment: Actually I was hoping for something like the console window in xcode where you can see console output without having to change any code.  A log showing stdout would do fine too.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Edit 2021, Visual Studio 2019**

To write debug messages to the Output window use the [OutputDebugStringA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-outputdebugstringa) from `debugapi.h` (include windows.h)

**test.c**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdShow, int nCmdShow)
{
    int number = 10;
    char str[256];
    sprintf_s(str, sizeof(str), "It works! - number: %d \n", number);

    OutputDebugStringA(str);

    return 0;
}
```

Tested on Visual Studio 2019, Debug / x64.

Or alternatively utilize my drop-in [header](https://github.com/rbento/cpp-visual-studio-log/blob/main/OutputDebug.h) file.

Comment: Obviously the 256 is there only for example but I like this approach.  Definitely what I had in mind.

Comment: Sure, just an example. You may wrap it in a class/function for convenience. Glad it helped! Cheers!

Comment: `wchar_t str[256];
    wsprintf(str, L"It works! - number: %d \n", number);
    OutputDebugString(str);`

Comment: This works, but adding a temporary buffer is tedious. I like Han's answer of showing the console in addition to the UI, then I can just use `printf`.

Answer (score 21):

You'll need a console window.  By far the easiest way to get one is to change a linker option: Project + Properties, Linker, System, SubSystem = Console.  Add a main() method:

```
int main() {
    return _tWinMain(GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, GetCommandLine(), SW_SHOW);
}
```

Comment: `_tWinMain` is the main function instead called `WinMain` for a Win32 application

Comment: In my case wWinMain. Anyway, thank you so much for this answer. I was going nuts with all the other answers I could find on the internet. A console separate from the UI was the best thing possible.

Answer (score 17):

I know that I have done this in the past using the [AllocConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944(VS.85).aspx) function, but I also recall that it was just a little trickier than I expected.

A quick Google search on AllocConsole yields what is apparently a [Windows Developer Journal article](http://www.halcyon.com/~ast/dload/guicon.htm) that seems relevant. From there, the following seems similar to what I recall, vague as it is.

```
void SetStdOutToNewConsole()
{
    int hConHandle;
    long lStdHandle;
    FILE *fp;

    // Allocate a console for this app
    AllocConsole();

    // Redirect unbuffered STDOUT to the console
    lStdHandle = (long)GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    hConHandle = _open_osfhandle(lStdHandle, _O_TEXT);
    fp = _fdopen(hConHandle, "w");
    *stdout = *fp;

    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
}
```

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work with coloured output

Comment: To use `_open_osfhandle()`, you need to `#include <io.h>`, and to use `_O_TEXT`, you need to `#include <fcntl.h>`.

Comment: Is this working for people on current windows 10? Because it's not for me. Definitely working in the past.

Answer (score 13):

Another way which wouldn't require changing existing printf's and also print to VS output window would go something like this:

```
#define printf printf2

int __cdecl printf2(const char *format, ...)
{
    char str[1024];

    va_list argptr;
    va_start(argptr, format);
    int ret = vsnprintf(str, sizeof(str), format, argptr);
    va_end(argptr);

    OutputDebugStringA(str);

    return ret;
}

...

printf("remains %s", "the same");
```

Comment: you're a genius!

Answer (score 10):

Thanks **torak** for your answer. It helped me a lot.

I needed a bigger scroll back buffer so made a few additions after taking a look at the [API functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Shared here in case it helps anybody else:

```
void SetStdOutToNewConsole()
{
    // allocate a console for this app
    AllocConsole();

    // redirect unbuffered STDOUT to the console
    HANDLE consoleHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    int fileDescriptor = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)consoleHandle, _O_TEXT);
    FILE *fp = _fdopen( fileDescriptor, "w" );
    *stdout = *fp;
    setvbuf( stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );

    // give the console window a nicer title
    SetConsoleTitle(L"Debug Output");

    // give the console window a bigger buffer size
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    if ( GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(consoleHandle, &csbi) )
    {
        COORD bufferSize;
        bufferSize.X = csbi.dwSize.X;
        bufferSize.Y = 9999;
        SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(consoleHandle, bufferSize);
    }
}
```

This increases the scroll back (screen buffer) height to 9999 lines.

Tested on Windows XP and Windows 7.

Comment: To save lookups for cut-and-pasters like me, one also needs to include <io.h> and <fcntl.h> for the function and flags definitions

Answer (score 3):

[Here is a page that will tell you how to do this, including sample code.](http://www.halcyon.com/~ast/dload/guicon.htm)

You must create a console window using AllocConsole(), then associate the C standard file handles to the HANDLEs of the new console window.

Comment: 3 lines of code which solved it for me with `AllocConsole()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55459226/197979

Answer (score 2):

Following is a working code

```
FILE* fpFile;
AllocConsole(); // or AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS); // if parent has one
freopen_s(&fpFile,"CONOUT$", "w", stdout); // redirect stdout to console
freopen_s(&fpFile,"CONOUT$", "w", stderr); // redirect stderr to console
freopen_s(&fpFile,"CONIN$", "r", stdin); // redirect stdin to console
```

Comment: Hi Davit, welcome to SO. Please take a look at the existing answers before adding your own. This is an old question and your answer nearly duplicates others that have already been posted.

Comment: Simple and effective. The most voted answer didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

For MinGW use "_A_SYSTEM" instead "_O_TEXT".
So ported **Quintin Willison** answer is as follows:

```
#include <io.h>
void SetStdOutToNewConsole()
{
  // allocate a console for this app
  AllocConsole();
  // redirect unbuffered STDOUT to the console
  HANDLE consoleHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  int fileDescriptor = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)consoleHandle, _A_SYSTEM);
  FILE *fp = _fdopen( fileDescriptor, "w" );
  *stdout = *fp;
  setvbuf( stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );
  // give the console window a nicer title
  SetConsoleTitle(L"Debug Output");
  // give the console window a bigger buffer size
  CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
  if ( GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(consoleHandle, &csbi) )
  {
    COORD bufferSize;
    bufferSize.X = csbi.dwSize.X;
    bufferSize.Y = 9999;
    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(consoleHandle, bufferSize);
  }
}
```