# Where can I see printf output in an mfc applcation?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, mfc

Where can I see printf output in an mfc application during debugging?

Is there a "console" window I can view in the debugger?

(Visual Studio C++ 6.0)

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009042/how-to-view-printf-output-in-win32-app-on-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the API OutputDebugString, the strings you output will appear in the Visual C Output window (in debug mode). In release mode, you'll need a separate app to capture them, such as DBWIN32.EXE

The advantage of using a separate application is that you can get debug output from several applications serialised into a single window, which can be very handy for debugging some scenarios.

The downside of course is that you can get debug output from other apps (nothing to do with your own) appearing because they've forgotten to flag out their debug in the release build. TRACE will do this automatically, but of course there might be cases where you WANT to get at the output in the release build. I prefer to be in charge, so I wsprintf/sprintf into a string, use OutputDebugString, and retain that control for myself.

Answer (score 4):

This is how it is done:

```
// for OutputDebugString
#include "Windows.h"

// ...

// fill in the message
char message[2000];

// fill in the variables
int var1 = ...;
int var2 = ...;

// fill in the message string and output it
sprintf(message, "... format %d,%d", var1, var2);
OutputDebugString((LPCSTR)message);
```

It should appear in output window. (It needs to be cast into `LPCSTR`.)

Answer (score 2):

I used to use the TRACE family of macros 
`TRACE0`, `TRACE1`,... etc
They behave like the printf. The 0, 1, 2,... etc suffices specify the number of arguments the macro can take (printf uses a va_list open number of argument)