# Can't see Windows program's stdout in console (compiled with Clang on Windows)

Tags: c, windows, winapi, clang

When I build a simple console app with clang, it works fine:

`void main() { puts("HELLO"); }`

But when I create a Windows app with `WinMain`, I can't see stdout.

There must be a flag that fixes it, like MinGW's `-mconsole`

Comment: You can open a console window with: [`AllocConsole()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/allocconsole).

Comment: Clang is just the compiler, it is the linker that determines what subsystem you target.  So you'll have to tell us what linker you use.

Comment: @HansPassant clang uses link.exe

Comment: I never had trouble using ordinary `main` function from within GUI applications, too, so far. I wouldn't use WinMain, no matter whatever else MS guys tell...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick stdout-enabler for otherwise GUI apps:

```
if (AllocConsole())
{
    FILE* fi = 0;
    freopen_s(&fi, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
}
```

and then `std::cout` and `printf` work.

Comment: You are a hero! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

`WinMain` is a custom microsoft entry function for a windows graphical application (with windows and menus etc). It doesn't have a console by default.

If you want a console program you should just use the standard `main` function.

If you want a graphical application (`WinMain`) that also has a console, then that's a little bit of work. Check [How do I get console output in C++ with a Windows program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191842/how-do-i-get-console-output-in-c-with-a-windows-program) on how to achieve that.